# IONIC - The type or namespace name 'Windows' could not be found - phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner

Tags: javascript, c#, cordova, ionic-framework, plugins

While building IONIC app for Windows which uses phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner, shows error

> The type or namespace name 'Windows' could not be found

Here it is,

```
F:\A_LHS_Projects\DynamicApp\DA_Code\AA\DynamicApp_V3>ionic build windows
```

(node:6520) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" F:\A_LHS_Projects\DynamicApp\DA_Code\AA\DynamicApp_V3\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js F:\A_LHS_Projects\DynamicApp\DA_Code\AA\DynamicApp_V3

add to body class: platform-windows

Building project: F:\A_LHS_Projects\DynamicApp\DA_Code\AA\DynamicApp_V3\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows.jsproj

```
    Configuration : debug
    Platform      : anycpu
```

Patching 8.1 in prebuild event...

Injected base.js reference to the www/index.html

Removing /( *)(\s*</script>)(\s*)/ from www/index.html
  Removing /( *)(\s*</script>)(\s*)/ from www/index.html

Reader.cs(17,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Windows' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [F:\A_LHS_Projects\DynamicApp\DA_Code\AA\DynamicApp_V3\plugins\phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner\src\windows\lib\WinRTBarcodeReader.csproj]

Reader.cs(18,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Windows' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [F:\A_LHS_Projects\DynamicApp\DA_Code\AA\DynamicApp_V3\plugins\phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner\src\windows\lib\WinRTBarcodeReader.csproj]
Reader.cs(19,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Windows' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [F:\A_LHS_Projects\DynamicApp\DA_Code\AA\DynamicApp_V3\plugins\phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner\src\windows\lib\WinRTBarcodeReader.csproj]
Reader.cs(20,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Windows' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [F:\A_LHS_Projects\DynamicApp\DA_Code\AA\DynamicApp_V3\plugins\phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner\src\windows\lib\WinRTBarcodeReader.csproj]
Reader.cs(21,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Windows' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [F:\A_LHS_Projects\DynamicApp\DA_Code\AA\DynamicApp_V3\plugins\phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner\src\windows\lib\WinRTBarcodeReader.csproj]
Reader.cs(72,26): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MediaCapture' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [F:\A_LHS_Projects\DynamicApp\DA_Code\AA\DynamicApp_V3\plugins\phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner\src\windows\lib\WinRTBarcodeReader.csproj]
Reader.cs(91,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IAsyncOperation<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [F:\A_LHS_Projects\DynamicApp\DA_Code\AA\DynamicApp_V3\plugins\phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner\src\windows\lib\WinRTBarcodeReader.csproj]
Reader.cs(91,32): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Result' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [F:\A_LHS_Projects\DynamicApp\DA_Code\AA\DynamicApp_V3\plugins\phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner\src\windows\lib\WinRTBarcodeReader.csproj]
Reader.cs(112,28): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Result' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [F:\A_LHS_Projects\DynamicApp\DA_Code\AA\DynamicApp_V3\plugins\phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner\src\windows\lib\WinRTBarcodeReader.csproj]
Reader.cs(136,28): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Result' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [F:\A_LHS_Projects\DynamicApp\DA_Code\AA\DynamicApp_V3\plugins\phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner\src\windows\lib\WinRTBarcodeReader.csproj]
Reader.cs(35,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'BarcodeReader' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [F:\A_LHS_Projects\DynamicApp\DA_Code\AA\DynamicApp_V3\plugins\phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner\src\windows\lib\WinRTBarcodeReader.csproj]
Reader.cs(45,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MediaCapture' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [F:\A_LHS_Projects\DynamicApp\DA_Code\AA\DynamicApp_V3\plugins\phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner\src\windows\lib\WinRTBarcodeReader.csproj]
Reader.cs(50,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ImageEncodingProperties' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [F:\A_LHS_Projects\DynamicApp\DA_Code\AA\DynamicApp_V3\plugins\phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner\src\windows\lib\WinRTBarcodeReader.csproj]
Reader.cs(60,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'InMemoryRandomAccessStream' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [F:\A_LHS_Projects\DynamicApp\DA_Code\AA\DynamicApp_V3\plugins\phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner\src\windows\lib\WinRTBarcodeReader.csproj]

Error: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe: Command failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

I created sample barcode scanner app and its working fine.
I used the same plugin which you used it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function scan(){
    console.log("clicked");
    cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(function(result){
    //success callback
    alert(JSON.stringify(result));
    document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = result.text;

 },function(error){
    //error callback
    alert(JSON.stringify(error));

  });
 }
 </script>
```

and the HTML code is

```
<body>
 <h3>BAR CODE SCANNER</h3>
 <button onclick="scan()">SCAN</button>
 <br /><br />
 Value is  :: <div id="data"></div>
</body>
```

I test this and its working fine.